# ASP.NET Core Web API 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to build an API within the ASP.NET Core framework. I've made a basic controller which just returns a string:

```
namespace Dojo_Api.Controllers.Forum
{
    //[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller")]
    public class ForumController : Controller
    {
        private MainContext _context;

        public ForumController(MainContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "string";
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access the API via Postman, I receive a 500 Internal Server Error:

[image]

I have already tried changing the port, which didn't work. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you debug and check if the controller is hit or not? If it's being executed then is there any exceptions during execution?

Comment: @Peurr your `ForumController` constructor contains a parameter. have you injected the dependency ?

Comment: Add a parameterless constructor: public ForumController(){}

Comment: Controller route missing a closing square bracket here `[Route("api/[controller")]` unless that was a typo when question was written

Comment: Just curious more than anything, where have you seen `[Route("api/[controller]")]` used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller route missing a closing square bracket here `[Route("api/[controller")]` unless that was a typo when question was written.

it should be

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ForumController : Controller { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/forum")]
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    private MainContext _context;

    public ForumController()
    {
        _context = new MainContext();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "string";
    }
}
```

Please try this